# How to normalize the column which contains JSON in data frame and get a complete data frame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in which one column contains JSON data

| Student_Id | V_Id | Json_result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32101 | 35 | [{"q_id":"8007","q_text":"வேறுபட்ட பொம்மை எது?","q_img":"","subject":"Tamil","q_medium":"Tamil","Skill":"0","Class":"1std","LO ID":"105","MC":"1","LO Text":"ஓவியம் மற்றும் படங்களின் வெளிப்படையான மற்றும் மறைமுகமான கூறுகளை நுட்பமாக உற்று நோக்குதல்.","notes":"","isAnswered":"1","correctAnswerId":["1"],"isAnswerCorrect":"1","answer":"1"},{"q_id":"8008","q_text":"","q_img":"8008_Set_3.png","subject":"Tamil","q_medium":"Tamil","Skill":"0","Class":"1std","LO ID":"106","MC":"1","LO Text":"கதை, சூழல், நிகழ்வைத் தொடர்ச்சியான படங்கள் மற்றும் இவற்றில் இடம் பெறும் செயல்பாடுகள் பற்றி பேசுதல்.","notes":"(படம் பார்த்துக் கதையை மிகச் சரியாகக் கூறினால் 'சிறப்பு', சரியாகக் கூறினால் 'அருமை', கதையைக் கூறவில்லை என்றால் 'சிந்திக்க' என்பதைத் தன்னார்வலர் தேர்ந்தெடுக்கவும்.)","isAnswered":"1","correctAnswerId":["1","2"],"isAnswerCorrect":"","answer":"3"},{"q_id":"8009","q_text":"","q_img":"8009_Set_3.png","subject":"Tamil","q_medium":"Tamil","Skill":"0","Class":"1std","LO ID":"109","MC":"1","LO Text":"அச்சடிக்கப்பட்ட குறிப்பிட்ட எழுத்தை அடையாளம் காணுதல்.","notes":"","isAnswered":"1","correctAnswerId":["1"],"isAnswerCorrect":"1","answer":"1"}] |
| 32102 | 35 | [{"q_id":"8007","q_text":"வேறுபட்ட பொம்மை எது?","q_img":"","subject":"Tamil","q_medium":"Tamil","Skill":"0","Class":"1std","LO ID":"105","MC":"1","LO Text":"ஓவியம் மற்றும் படங்களின் வெளிப்படையான மற்றும் மறைமுகமான கூறுகளை நுட்பமாக உற்று நோக்குதல்.","notes":"","isAnswered":"1","correctAnswerId":["1"],"isAnswerCorrect":"1","answer":"1"},{"q_id":"8008","q_text":"","q_img":"8008_Set_3.png","subject":"Tamil","q_medium":"Tamil","Skill":"0","Class":"1std","LO ID":"106","MC":"1","LO Text":"கதை, சூழல், நிகழ்வைத் தொடர்ச்சியான படங்கள் மற்றும் இவற்றில் இடம் பெறும் செயல்பாடுகள் பற்றி பேசுதல்.","notes":"(படம் பார்த்துக் கதையை மிகச் சரியாகக் கூறினால் 'சிறப்பு', சரியாகக் கூறினால் 'அருமை', கதையைக் கூறவில்லை என்றால் 'சிந்திக்க' என்பதைத் தன்னார்வலர் தேர்ந்தெடுக்கவும்.)","isAnswered":"1","correctAnswerId":["1","2"],"isAnswerCorrect":"","answer":"3"},{"q_id":"8009","q_text":"","q_img":"8009_Set_3.png","subject":"Tamil","q_medium":"Tamil","Skill":"0","Class":"1std","LO ID":"109","MC":"1","LO Text":"அச்சடிக்கப்பட்ட குறிப்பிட்ட எழுத்தை அடையாளம் காணுதல்.","notes":"","isAnswered":"1","correctAnswerId":["1"],"isAnswerCorrect":"1","answer":"1"}] |

I would like to normalize the JSON content in the attributes column so the JSON attributes become each a column in the dataframe. There are more than 40k rows in the dataframe.

The json sample in a single row is in the form as follows

```
[
  {
    "q_id": "8007",
    "q_text": "வேறுபட்ட பொம்மை எது?",
    "q_img": "",
    "subject": "Tamil",
    "q_medium": "Tamil",
    "Skill": "0",
    "Class": "1std",
    "LO ID": "105",
    "MC": "1",
    "LO Text": "ஓவியம் மற்றும் படங்களின் வெளிப்படையான மற்றும் மறைமுகமான கூறுகளை நுட்பமாக உற்று நோக்குதல்.",
    "notes": "",
    "isAnswered": "1",
    "correctAnswerId": [
      "1"
    ],
    "isAnswerCorrect": "1",
    "answer": "1"
  },
  {
    "q_id": "8008",
    "q_text": "",
    "q_img": "8008_Set_3.png",
    "subject": "Tamil",
    "q_medium": "Tamil",
    "Skill": "0",
    "Class": "1std",
    "LO ID": "106",
    "MC": "1",
    "LO Text": "கதை, சூழல், நிகழ்வைத் தொடர்ச்சியான படங்கள் மற்றும் இவற்றில் இடம் பெறும் செயல்பாடுகள் பற்றி பேசுதல்.",
    "notes": "(படம் பார்த்துக் கதையை மிகச் சரியாகக் கூறினால் 'சிறப்பு', சரியாகக் கூறினால் 'அருமை', கதையைக் கூறவில்லை என்றால் 'சிந்திக்க' என்பதைத் தன்னார்வலர் தேர்ந்தெடுக்கவும்.)",
    "isAnswered": "1",
    "correctAnswerId": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ],
    "isAnswerCorrect": "",
    "answer": "3"
  },
  {
    "q_id": "8009",
    "q_text": "",
    "q_img": "8009_Set_3.png",
    "subject": "Tamil",
    "q_medium": "Tamil",
    "Skill": "0",
    "Class": "1std",
    "LO ID": "109",
    "MC": "1",
    "LO Text": "அச்சடிக்கப்பட்ட குறிப்பிட்ட எழுத்தை அடையாளம் காணுதல்.",
    "notes": "",
    "isAnswered": "1",
    "correctAnswerId": [
      "1"
    ],
    "isAnswerCorrect": "1",
    "answer": "1"
  }
]
```

I want to link the student for the json q_id and want an output as follows

| Student_Id | V_Id | q_id | subject | q_medium | Class | LO_ID | isAnswered | correctAnswerId | isAnswerCorrect | answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 32101 | 35 | 8007 | Tamil | Tamil | 1std | 105 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 32101 | 35 | 8008 | Tamil | Tamil | 1std | 106 | 1 | [1,2] | - | 3 |
| 32101 | 35 | 8009 | Tamil | Tamil | 1std | 109 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 32102 | 35 | 8007 | Tamil | Tamil | 1std | 105 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 32102 | 35 | 8008 | Tamil | Tamil | 1std | 106 | 1 | [1,2] | - | 3 |
| 32102 | 35 | 8009 | Tamil | Tamil | 1std | 109 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Like this I want to get the dataframe for 40k ID and rows. How do I write in python to get this kind of data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may start by using `df.explode()` and using loop and `.apply(lambda)` to get the value of each key in `Json Result`, as shown in example below

```py
import json

df['Json_result'] = df['Json_result'].apply(lambda x: json.loads(x))
df = df.explode('Json_result')
keys = df['Json_result'].tolist()[0].keys() # Get the list of keys in json
for column in keys: # loop to create new column by getting the value from the dict
    df[column] = df['Json_result'].apply(lambda x: x.get(column, None))
```

Comment: Hi I tried this code, but I'm getting an error.  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'. Can you help me in this

Comment: it means the value in `Json Result` column are string. So, you first need to apply `json.loads` to the value to transform the string to python dictionary. I have updated my solution to fixed your issue :)

Comment: Sry for the trouble, Now it shows an error 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'.

Comment: I previously thought that your `Json Result` data are the list of string like `['{}','{}']`. But, with your latest error, it seem like data are all string e.g. `'[{},{}]'`. So, I have updated my solution for fixing your problem :)